# Not getting all elements while scraping with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the sportsbook page but having trouble retrieving all the elements from the page. Here is my code so far:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
import re


webdriver_service = Service('C:/Users/tmarkac/source/repos/chromedriver.exe') #Your chromedriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service)
team_name = 'Anja Petkovic'

u =f'https://superbet.pl/wyszukaj?query={team_name}'


url = driver.get(u)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]').click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'pick__more-odds').click()

#options = Options()     # This part should translate the page to english but its not working
#prefs = {
#  "translate_whitelists": {"pl":"en"},
#  "translate":{"enabled":"true"}
#}
#options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
#browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/tmarkac/source/repos/chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=options)
    


soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
time.sleep(5)

markets = soup.find_all('div', class_ ='event-row__expanded-market')
market_list = []
for  market in markets:
     market_name = market.find('span', class_='event-row__expanded-market-title').text.strip()
     market_list.append(market_name)
print(market_list)
```

I am trying to get a list of all market names and can only get the 1st one. The problem is in this line of code:

```
markets = soup.find_all('div', class_ ='event-row__expanded-market')
```

as it is not getting all markets rather than just 1st one(even though they have the same class name and thus the same locating criteria. Also, it would make my life easier if a page could get translated from Polish to English - part of the code which was supposed to do that is not doing the job so I commented it out. FYI,

```
team_name = 'Anja Petkovic'
```

is the input I use for locating the match on the site(being played atm). Any other match can be used for example. Thank you.

Comment: I tried with Andy Murray and got a list of 22 as I should have... (btw I get a No Results page with Anja Petkovic). But I didn't use `webdriver_service` - just directly `driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)`. I actually get an error (*"got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'"*) when I try with `webdriver_service`. Are you using that for a specific reason?

Comment: I tried the URL with the team name you mentioned, but it doesn't display any data. Can you pls post the correct URL.

Comment: Anja Petkovic's name probably won't work unless she is playing at the exact time you are running the code. So the procedure is to pass in any Team/Player name as team_name variable which gets in the URL's query part and finds that exact match on the site. Also, I made a big mistake in my post regarding the translation part which I will change right away.

Answer (score 1):

You can verify your class selector by using chrome developer tool. Press `F12` > select `Search` > press `Ctrl + F`.

Type in the class as `.event-row__expanded-market`. Check the divs found with that class attribute.

For the case of translating the language. You have to enable chrome translate feature by Using the following codes.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {
  "translate_whitelists": {"po":"en"},
  "translate":{"enabled":"True"}
}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

You have to pass in `chrome_options=options` kwargs on **webdriver, Chrome class**

Comment: I copied your code and I am getting an error: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in the path. But even when I add a path it is not translating the page just opens new empty browser.

Comment: About the error, make sure the path to the `chrome driver`  is on `environments variable`  > `System variable`> `Path`. Add new path and You will never see the error 'executable needs to be in path'. It should be able to translate your chrome page. You can check this post on medium for further clarity  [https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-modify-the-website-language-using-selenium-python-bindings-780c2211324d